# ToolTip for picturebox and image map

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, picturebox, mousemove

I have a `PictureBox` that has a map assigned to it (basically a list of `Rectangle` objects). Now I want to make it such if user moves the mouse over this picturebox, and if the mouse is over a rectangle that is existing in the list, a tooltip pop up and show some information.

The mapping works fine, but problem is the `ToolTip` is going crazy and does not show up properly, it just continues poping up with any mouse move. How can I code it such it only pop up when the mouse is in the rectangle?

This is my code and down there you see the example!

```
private void pictureBoxPackageView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (PackageMap == null || PackageMap.Count == 0) return;
    var point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

    foreach (var map in PackageMap)
    {
        if (map.Rectangle.Contains(point))
        {
            var tip = new ToolTip();
            tip.ToolTipTitle = map.Pin.Group;
            tip.Show("Result: " + map.Pin.Mk2Result, pictureBoxPackageView, point, 200);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It continuously pops up because you are only checking if the cursor is inside a rectangle. Remember that you can still move the mouse several times but your still within that rectangle.

I think what you want is to pop up the tooltip only once when you enter a rectangle. 
You should remember the previous location of the mouse. If the current location is within a rectangle check if the previous location is not in the same rectangle. This is the time to display the tooltip otherwise pass.

Answer (score 3):

I would add a custom listener to detect the [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx) Event and [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx) Event for each separate rectangular container you want a distinct tooltip to display for, adding the code to display the tooltip for X seconds on MouseEnter (use the [Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67fds2ee.aspx) method to display). If the user keeps his cursor inside the rectangle, it will continue to display for those X seconds (use the [AutoPopDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.autopopdelay) property to automatically hide after those X seconds). If the user moves his cursor out, the MouseLeave Event should then use the [Hide()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.hide.aspx) method.

I would also set a one second delay to keep several tooltips from opening when you move the cursor across several areas at once. Use the [InitialDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.initialdelay) property for this.

Should look something like this (doesn't show the properties being set appropriately):

```
private void area1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tooltip.Show("text to display", window);
}

private void area1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tooltip.Hide(window);
}
```

The route I'd go would be to extend the container you're using and add these listeners to a custom container class, especially if you're creating several similar containers that all need this functionality.